# Multi-project solution in Visual Studio: spread the config of the main project

Tags: c++, visual-studio, architecture, projects, solution

I have a C++ solution in Visual Studio (2012 Express) containing 15 projects.

1 is defined as the main project (the one that is first built as the whole solution is built).

All the 15 projects have 2 **same** external dependencies. I mean I have to add the 2 same folders to Project Properties > Configuration Properties > VC++ Directories.

This is a bit boring to do this manually.

Is there a way to add the required dependencies only to the main project and to tell VC11 to replicate this configuration to the other 14 projects in my solution?

Comment: if they are in the same solution, You can select all the projects and common properties will be avaliable to set

Comment: yes, they are in the same solution.  how do i make the properties available to set ? where do i find this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You select multiple nodes - see this pic:

[image]
right click and select properties....

N.B. Forgot in my original answer - don't forget to select the correct Configs (Or all configs)

Comment: Wow, I am mind blown! I used to do this just as I answered below!

But, one note: I think that if you want to just ADD new directories without messing with each project's configurations (if they're different for some reason) you might need to do as I answered below. Otherwise, this is a much better way to do that!

By the way, just +1'd

Comment: @Guarita yep you are right, I tend to add all the common, then possibly add specifics after - in fact in my screenshot you can see that for those I selected they are highlighted as different - if I were to change this in the screen  - then I'd overwrite the old differences.

Answer (score 2):

I use VC++ Express 2008 but I think it should work as well:

1:Open the property pages and put the dependencies on the first project.

2:After that, copy the text with the dependencies directories from the input text box.

3:Click on the next project on the Solution Explorer (or whatever the box with the projects and source code files is called on VC2012). The same property page of that project will be open.

4:Just paste the text after whatever is written there.

5:If there are any projects left to change: go to step 3.